# Validating XML documents against schemas nested inside wsdl:types

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd, nokogiri, xsd-validation

I have XML files that I need to validate against XSDs that are nested inside a `<wsdl:types></wsdl:types>` in a WSDL file retrieved from a web service.

Inside the `<wsdl:types></wsdl:types>` there are several `<xs:schema>`s. I am using the ruby gem `nokogiri` to load the XML files and validate them against said XSDs, however, I am getting following error when I run the program:

```
Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope': No 
matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

So far I have extracted out the `<xs:schema>`s (all 4 of them) and copied them into a `schema.xsd` file.

**Code**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

def validate(document_path, schema_path)
  schema = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read(schema_path))
  document = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(document_path))
  schema.validate(document)
end


validate('data.xml', 'schema.xsd').each do |error|
  puts error.message
end
```

So basically my `schema.xsd` has multiple `<xs:schema>`s in there, which I do not think in and of itself is a problem because `nokogiri` didn't throw errors when I instantiated the `schema` object.

**schema.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
  <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <!-- data in here -->
</xs:schema>

<!-- three more xs:schema tags removed for brevity -->
```

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header />
  <env:Body>
    <CreatePerson xmlns="https://person.example.com/">
      <oMessageType xmlns:epa="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/whatever" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:array="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <person:bodyField>
            <!-- data in here -->
        </person:bodyField>
        <!-- more data in here -->
      </oMessageType>
    </CreatePerson>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WSDL not the XSD scheam so you need to extract the schema partial manually or automatic by programming.

Here is the sample code, you need to refactor it and using in your codes.

```
str = <<EOF
    <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="HelloService" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
          <element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="anyType"/>
          <element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="anyURI"/>
          <!-- data in here -->
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="SayHelloRequest">
        <part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="SayHelloResponse">
        <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="Hello_PortType">
        <operation name="sayHello">
            <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="sayHello">
            <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="Hello_Service">
        <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
        <port name="Hello_Port" binding="tns:Hello_Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>

EOF

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(str)

doc.root.children.each do |child|
    if child.node_name == 'types'
        types = child 
        # p types.inner_html
        xsd_doc = Nokogiri::XML(types.inner_html)

        # p xsd_doc.root

        xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema.from_document xsd_doc.root
    end
end
```

Comment: I went ahead and refactored my code like how you have here, but I still got the same error message: https://pastebin.com/4Kutuqdh

Comment: @hyde Mainly the idea is search the embedded schema element and create a new document, then you can create the xsd against the new document. That's it. My sample code is a working copy, but for project propose, this code is not beauty, for testing, you can copy your wsdl string to replace the `str`.

Comment: right. That's what your code does- extract the schema from WSDL. However, when I try to validate the data using the extracted schema, I still get the same error: Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope': No 
matching global declaration available for the validation root.

Comment: Suppose your should validate the content in the SOAP body part, as your schema is define this xml, but not the full envelope.